# Why inline style definition is not applied

Tags: css, css-selectors

Im developing google sheet side bar.
For that link to google side bar css package is used.

`bt1` has an inline `style background-color` declarations with `important!`.

however when page loads the color is something gray.
I went over the google css trying to understand, with not much success.

`bt2.onClick()` - change `bt1.disable`. You can see the inline statement have effect only when bt1is disabled.
If not linking to google css - behavior as expected.

My understanding is that inline style must always win. especially when specifying `important!`

my questions are:

1. Is this statement true in 100% cases?
2. If not - in what cases?
3. Is there a way to overcome that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">


</head>
<body>
    <button id="bt1" style="background-color: rgb(43, 226, 137) !important;">bt1</button>
    <button id="bt2" onclick="bt2OnClick()">bt2</button>

<script>
  function bt2OnClick(){
    let bt = document.getElementById("bt1");

    // Switch state
    bt.disabled = !bt.disabled;
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception If you want to overrule a specific inline style with a CSS rule, then it may be ok to use !important though many would even disagree with that statement as the meaning os CSS is `cascading` style sheets as `!important` breaks the flow of CSS. ***Something to consider when using !important...***

Comment: Have you tried setting the inline style using JS?

Comment: @dalelandry yes. Same behavior. external css somehow win

Comment: @dalelandry I added `important!` because it didn't work, and I was just trying to force it. I actually was not familiar with that before. I understand the cons of it, but as I understand, this is exactly the scenario `important` is needed.

Comment: No you dont need `!important` check the answer below :)

Comment: Consider `!important` like a cheat-mode (intended for playtesters). It's a useful tool when you're developing but you should never need to use it in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style is in fact being applied but the `add-ons1.css`your adding add a `background` property with a `linear-gradient`so your `background-color` does not change the `background-image` property that represent the gradient

So if you want to override it, just select the `background` property instead of `background-color`

And you dont need you `!important` anymore :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">


</head>
<body>
    <button id="bt1" style="background: rgb(43, 226, 137)">bt1</button>
    <button id="bt2" onclick="bt2OnClick()">bt2</button>

<script>
  function bt2OnClick(){
    let bt = document.getElementById("bt1");

    // Switch state
    bt.disabled = !bt.disabled;
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok. I now understand this is not a css priority thing but two attributes "clashing" . I actually didn't really need that, just discovered while debugging. can you refer me to the line in the addon?

Comment: Starting at line 151 
`.button,
button,
input[type="button"],
input[type="image"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {...}`